# Comparator not sorting -2147483648 properly

Tags: java, binary-tree, comparator, inorder

Trying to sort [5,3,9,-2147483648,2] using comparator where the values are TreeNodes

Structure of TreeNode:

```
public class TreeNode {
     int val;
     TreeNode left;
     TreeNode right;
     TreeNode() {}
     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
         this.val = val;
         this.left = left;
         this.right = right;
     }
 }
```

Below is my code :

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<>(){
            public int compare(TreeNode a,TreeNode b)
            {
                return a.val-b.val;
            }
        });
```

Here list is collection of TreeNodes

Actual Output : 2,3,5,9,-2147483648

Expected Output : -2147483648,2,3,5,9

Comment: Try printing what e.g `9 - (-2147483648)` is or `(-2147483648) - 9`.

Comment: `return Integer.compare(a.val, b.val);`

Comment: In short: use `Integer::compare` when comparing integers. Do not use arithmetic, as it is subject to overflow.

Answer (score 4):

```
return a.val-b.val;
```

This, like all integer arithmetic, is subject to overflow if the operands are too large.

Instead, you can use:

```
return Integer.compare(a.val, b.val);
```

Or, better, construct the `Comparator` using the helper method:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.val));
```

Answer (score 1):

So this happens because the result of the arithmetic operation overflows the max number allowed by `Integer`.

When doing the comparison at some point the loop does `return 9 - (-2147483648)` returning `2147483657` which is greater than the max value supported by integers `2147483647`.

The best option to avoid these scenarios is using the method `Integer.compare(a,b)` provided by Java as @andy-turner mentions in his answer.